# Get column from another entity using foreign keys in Room

Tags: android, kotlin, android-room

I have two different entities. One has two references to the other one and I need to get a attribute of the reference.

`my_main_table.primary_type` is a foreign key of `types._id` and `my_main_table.secondary_type` is a foreign key of `types._id` that can be null.

Is a prepopulated database copied using `RoomAsset` library, so the scheme is already done in the database. Here is the diagram of the database:

[image: database diagram]

Here is my main entity:

```
@Entity(
    tableName = "my_main_table",
    foreignKeys = [
        ForeignKey(
            entity = Type::class,
            parentColumns = ["_id"],
            childColumns = ["secondary_type"],
            onDelete = ForeignKey.RESTRICT,
            onUpdate = ForeignKey.RESTRICT
        ),
        ForeignKey(
            entity = Type::class,
            parentColumns = ["_id"],
            childColumns = ["primary_type"],
            onDelete = ForeignKey.RESTRICT,
            onUpdate = ForeignKey.RESTRICT
        )
    ]
)
data class MainTable(
    @PrimaryKey
    @ColumnInfo(name = "_id", index = true)
    val id: Int,

    @ColumnInfo(name = "number")
    val number: String,

    @ColumnInfo(name = "name")
    val name: String,

    @ColumnInfo(name = "primary_type")
    val primaryType: String,

    @ColumnInfo(name = "secondary_type")
    val secondaryType: String?
)
```

And here is my reference:

```
@Entity(tableName = "types")
data class Type(
    @PrimaryKey
    @ColumnInfo(name = "_id")
    val id: Int,

    @ColumnInfo(name = "name")
    val name: String
)
```

Finally the SQL code for `@Query`:

```sql
SELECT p._id AS _id,
    p.number AS number,
    p.name   AS name,
    pt.name  AS primary_type,
    st.name  AS secondary_type
FROM my_main_table p
    INNER JOIN types pt ON p.primary_type == pt._id
    LEFT JOIN types st ON p.secondary_type == st._id
```

What I want is to get the value of `types.name` throught the relation. But I can't figure out how. Should I need another method in my repository to get the value of the name?

Thanks.